# node-red return all flow variables

Tags: node-red

Is there anyway, using function, the return all `flow` variables?

My scenario is: I have a functions creating flow variable for each device connected, I want to get this variables to do future processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flow.keys()` to get a list of the names of all flow context variables.

Reference: https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#flow